# AWS Step Functions IF equivalent

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Im trying to do the following at AWS Step Functions:

- IF ExampleState fails, do "Next":"Anotherlambda"
- IF ExampleState completes successfull, end the execution.

How can i do that? The CHOICE state doesn't support ErrorEquals: States.TaskFailed.

In my case, when ExampleState fails, State Machine STOPS and gives me error, but i want to continue and catch some info from the error and save it with another lambda

Thanks!

Comment: Can you wrap lambda into the the try/catch block to prevent lambda termination due to the error, and then simply return the data of the error or the normal result if there was no error.

Comment: Hi Artem! Thank you for your answer. You can check the final result of how i did it on the next Answer. It was easier than i think, AWS always goes ahead and has easy implementation for this solutions:

Answer (score 2):

All i wanted AWS Step Functions to do is, if a State succeeded, finish the execution, if fails, run another lambda. Like an IF / ELSE on programming.

Step Functions gives this easy to you as a CATCH block that only activates if catches an error and does what you want. Here the solution:

```
"StartAt": "ExampleLambda",
"States": {
  "ExampleLambda": {
    "Type": "Task",
    "Resource": "xxx:function:ExampleLambda",
    "Catch": [
      {
        "ErrorEquals":["States.TaskFailed"],
        "Next": "SendToErrorQueue"
      }
    ],
    "End": true
  }
```

Comment: I also see a blog post by folks at Amazon about this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resume-aws-step-functions-from-any-state/

Comment: Thank you for your contribution @nitishagar, very interesting!